# JAX-WS web services: switching from console app to web app

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, web, war

I created the following three classes in a console application in Eclipse:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "uk.co.hello.Details")
public class DetailsImpl implements Details{
    public String getDetails() {

        return "Hello";
    }
}

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface Details{

    @WebMethod String getDetails();
}

public class DetailsPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9900/mytest", new DetailsImpl());
       System.out.println(endpoint.isPublished());
    }
}
```

Everything is fine and I can publish my web services and use it.

Now I created a web application and I want to do the same deploying my stuff on JBoss. Probably I don't need the main method anymore, but something else instead. Can someone give me an example on what I need to change in order to generate a working war?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your `EJB` as a `SOAP` service, but I have never heard anyone publishing SOAP service in web layer in war.

In order to make it work with JBoss supporting EJB 3.0:
a) **Specify EJB interface.**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface SOAPService extends Remote {
        String service();
}
```

b) **specify an EJB:**

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "full.package.and.name.of.SOAPService")
@Remote(SOAPService.class)
public class EchoBean {
        public String service() {
                return "SOAP Serviced";
        }
}
```

c) **Deploy on JBoss as EJB jar.**

d) **Test**

Answer (score 0):

If you know spring, you can use cxf framework a good tutorial can be found  [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_cxf_project.html) using eclipse. You can use bottom up approach